# How to find price reversal with RX.NET

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am learning RX and am trying to see if I can use it to tackle the following problem:
I have a stream of crypto coin prices and I am trying to find out when the price reversal starts happening during a pump. During these pumps the price of the coin goes up very quickly and when it starts to fall I want to do an action (sell order). However, sometimes it can stall a bit and then go further up, but mostly when it starts to fall it really falls.

I've managed to get the ticker stream going and calculating some delta's between them, in a way that will probably make you cringe (I'm misusing Scan method a bit):

```
public class Ticker
{
    public decimal Ask { get; set; }
    public decimal Bid { get; set; }
    public decimal Delta { get; set; }
    public decimal DeltaPercent { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {

        return $"a: {Ask} B:{Bid} D:{Delta} DP:{DeltaPercent} T:{Time}";
    }
}    

res.AsObservable().DistinctUntilChanged(x => x.Ask)
    .Scan((state, t) =>
    {
        var d =  t.Ask-state.Ask;
        t.Delta = d;
        t.DeltaPercent = t.Delta/state.Ask;
        return t;
    })
```

Now I'd like to figure when N consecutive deltas were less than X amount within T amount of time and when they are do something. I guess I'd have to group them somehow, but am at a loss at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't defined your problem tightly. But you will probably find your solution in some combination of these operators:

- [`Buffer`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/13_TimeShiftedSequences.html#Buffer) - groups items from an observable into a list based on a count, timespan, or custom logic
- [`Window`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/17_SequencesOfCoincidence.html#Window) - same as buffer, but instead of grouping into a list, groups into an observable
- [`TimeInterval`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/08_Transformation.html#TimeStampAndTimeInterval) - Wraps each item in an observable with a stamp telling you how much time has lapsed since the last item.
- `Scan` - Used for accumulating state (as you demonstrated)